# Not able to push data to real time database with react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am using this code to push to a real time database with NodeJS and this is working fine

```
import admin from "firebase-admin";


admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS),
  databaseURL: 'https://xxxxx1.firebasedatabase.app/'
});


var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("queue");

ref.child('tasks').push({"id": "Some ID"}).then(function(){ process.exit();});
```

I want to push the same data within a react-native App. I tried the following code, but nothing is happening.

```
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

   const newReference = database().ref('queue')
    newReference.child('tasks').push({
      id: "Some ID"
    })

    const reference = database().ref('/queue/tasks').push();
    reference
      .set({
        id: "Some ID",
      })
      .then(() => console.log('Data updated.'));
      .catch(function(error) {
  //error callback
  console.log('Something went wrong ', error)

  })
```

The rules edited so that everyone can push in the database

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you see  an error? You should add a `catch()` block to capture the potential errors.

Comment: Unfortunately no error are thrown

Comment: At first sight your code seems correct. It's difficult to help you more... Are you sure you are writing to the correct Firebase project? Did you try the [Rules playground](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator#use_the)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I missed this part in the documentation

> NOTE: To get a reference to a database other than an 'us-central1'
> default database, you must pass the database URL. You can find your
> Realtime Database URL in the Realtime Database section of the Firebase
> console.

```
// firebase should be imported and not database
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/database';

const reference = firebase
  .app()
  .database('https://<databaseName>.<region>.firebasedatabase.app/')
  .ref('/users/123');
```